# Android sdk 2.2

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

can we get API level 3 inbuilt in version 2.2 or we have to add it? as i am not able to update it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile your application as a 2.2 application, it should be working on lower API version provided you don't use any function/class that has been introduced later than that old API. What is the exact problem?

Comment: actually i am using android version 2.2 with API level 8 now i want to use google maps so i need API level 3 but in my sdk i dont have API with level 3 please guide me.

Comment: The Google APIs and the Android API are 2 different things, with each their own version number. You need to download the Google Maps API for Android, that should not be hard to find. It could also be  available in the update manager bundled with the SDK. See http://code.google.com/intl/fr/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html and http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/3753576/Mapping-with-Google-APIs-in-Android.htm